# Identity server Invalid reference token error

Tags: asp.net-identity, token, identityserver4, identity

currently running the latest version of identity server and using reference tokens to access an api. I have implemented IPersistedGrant store and can't see any issues saving or getting data from it. When testing I'm not getting any issues with invalid tokens and introspection is working as expected. I am however seeing my error logs filling up with |ERROR|Invalid reference token. When I take these token handles and test them locally, the data is being pulled out from the persisted grant store as I'd expect. From reading the TokenValidator code this error should only happen when nothing gets returned for the given token handle so i don't understand why it is happening. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that they're expired tokens?

Comment: expired tokens give a separate error message of token expired, see below a snippet of the identity server 4 default token validator class

Comment: if (token == null)
            {
                LogError("Invalid reference token.");
                return Invalid(OidcConstants.ProtectedResourceErrors.InvalidToken);
            }

            if (token.CreationTime.HasExceeded(token.Lifetime, _clock.UtcNow.UtcDateTime))
            {
                LogError("Token expired.");

                await _referenceTokenStore.RemoveReferenceTokenAsync(tokenHandle);
                return Invalid(OidcConstants.ProtectedResourceErrors.ExpiredToken);
            }

Comment: just doing some more digging its possible it could be this issue, but it appears they fixed it so will test it out https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1025

Comment: did you solve this? I'm getting the same in production, everything seems to work fine except logs filled with these errors.